# Deploying ios apps wirelessly .Enterprise apps

Tags: ios, deployment, installation, enterprise, ipa

I have developed an app in the in-house, enterprise mode. While testing i was using the iPad provided to me by my company. I tested on it. I had certificates from developer member center. Tested just fine.

Now I have deployed the files on our secure server.I have a link where the ".ipa" files are present. So i used my same testing iPad and downloaded the app from that link via safari on the iPad. It installed and ran successfully. Now i gave that link to another member of my team and he has his own iPad. When he clicks that link it starts installing but it doesn't finish.He gets an error.The error he gets is

`"Unable to download Application.XYZ app could not be installed at this time. Done .Retry."`

Same thing with another iPad. These iPads are NOT registered under testing on member center. So i have a thought. Since while testing i had certificates and all on my testing iPad, it might have recognized it and installed it.But the other completely new iPads are not identified. So how do i do it?How can i say my app that it is safe to install on so-so iPad that belongs to my co-worker. If i am not clear please ask.Thanks.

Comment: What kind of certificate (development or distribution) did you use to sign the ipa you put on the web site?  Should be a distribution vert.

Comment: @bobnoble . I used distribution and that too in-house.I create a new scheme.Check the checkbox for "share" and do all the steps. Still no go.Also in the organizer(Archives), "Validate" and "Distribute". Validate tries to connect to iTunes connect.But it says no username with "xyz@abc.com" found.So without this step can i move forward?Why am i not able to log into iTunes connect?Please help.Ask me questions so that i know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: You actually don't do the validate step with enterprise apps. You just click distribute ->  "Save For Enterprise or ..." -> Select the appropriate Distribution cert -> Wait a few minutes -> Save it to disk. (if you want it to create the plist file, check the box "Save for enterprise" and it will do it for you.)

Comment: @smcdrc. Thanks. So i skipped the step yesterday and went directly to distribute. It created .ipa and .plist files. I saved them to a secure server. Got a link from it. Tried to download it. Now, about after 70% installing( blue progress bar one usually sees while installing an app) it says this error "Unable to download application "XYZ" could not be installed at this time.Done Retry".What is going wrong?Also i have a question with .plist in my Xcode project. I set ONLY the bundle identifier exactly like on apple developer member center.All else i left it default.

Comment: @smcdrc.My XCODE .plist file looks like this.Bundle display name- ${PRODUCT_NAME}.Executable file ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.Bundle name - {PRODUCT_NAME}. All are default.Should they be changed mandatorily?

Comment: @smcdrc. I got it.My bad. I was not mentioning the Application URL. I was just pointing it to the folder location,not the actual .ipa file.Also i forgot to check the share check box while creating a new scheme.I did these two things and it works now.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bobnoble is correct. You need to have an Enterprise Distribution certificate to use with this. Development certs are similar to ad-hoc certs in that you need to individual identify the device UDID's that will be used.

We do a lot of work with enterprise customers and I never use the development certs, mainly just to cut down on the confusion. It might be a problem if one of our devs goes rouge :), but it is a chance we are willing to take.

Comment: @smcdrc.Thanks. I used the distribution certificate. Can you please read the comment i wrote above and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode you can select the Project or the Targets when assigning the provided profiles.

Make sure you sign the target.
There is a nice tutorial on the testflight site:
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused between a Distribution Certificate and an Enterprise Certificate. In your case you should use Enterprise or Adhoc Certificate. Enterprise certificate is not given to a person but organization and it is not created where other certs are created.